# Specific dates disappeared from Interesting Calendars

Tags: google-calendar

I have the French Holidays and UK Holidays shared calendars added to my Google Calendar, and in the last few days the Holidays around Easter 2011 have disappeared.

I have tried unsubscribing and subscribing but the data is still missing. I know these dates are in the past but it is useful for my records.

For an example, there should be a holiday for both calendars for 25th April 2011.

Any hints?

Comment: There's no Easter in Australia now either